# Quantum to classical mapping

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, path-integral, partition-function, wick-rotation

I'm having troubles understanding precisely how the mapping from a quantum system to a classical one works.

Let's say that I have a quantum system in $d$ dimensions with Hamiltonian $H$ at temperature $\frac{1}{\beta}$.

Then the quantum partition function $Z=Tr(e^{-\beta H})$ can be evaluated using path integral in euclidean time, because I can think of $e^{-\beta H}$ as a temporal evolution over imaginary time: in fact the usual evolution operator $e^{\frac{I\hat H t}{\hbar}}$ in imaginary time $t->i\tau$ becomes $e^{\frac{-\hat H \tau }{\hbar}}$ and if I evolve up to imaginary time $\tau=\hbar \beta$ I indeed get $e^{-\beta H}$.

What I don't understand is why this procedure brings us an expression that corresponds to the partition function of a classical system in $d+1$ dimensions.